# Is "why is x usually avoided" a valid question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I want to ask a question about url slugs, specifically if there is a reason why spaces are avoided in slugs. Is this a valid question here or on any SE site?

Comment: I personally would welcome that question, provided you put some examples and research into it, unless it's a duplicate (no idea), though it's probably near the border. Not sure whether [programmers.se] would be better...

Comment: As long as you word it so it's not "why is X bad practice" because this is too subjective. Users have "opinion" on why something is bad practice. You need to hone your question down to something specific, like "Do spaces in URL slugs cause problems for browsers" etc

Comment: A cursory search at Webmasters.SE shows a couple of questions about spaces in URLs, but mostly about SEO and with no good sources in the answers.  The tour is pretty useless as far as deciding whether your question would be on-topic there, and they don't seem to have a chat to check in.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I actually found an answer in one of those SEO questions: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32867/does-using-spaces-in-a-url-affect-seo.

Comment: @James: That seems too strict. A question like "Why are singletons bad practice?" seems perfectly fine to me, and it already [exists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137975) with nearly 1k upvotes, with just slightly different wording.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would include sources that claim it is "usually avoided". That way it's already verified that it's not just you having a misunderstanding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space

Comment: @James: asking the OP to hone the question into something specific like "Does X cause problems with Y" misses the point - they *don't know* what the downsides to using X are. It might not even cross the OP's mind that X would cause problems with Y, which is why they want to post the question.

Comment: A lot of the responses I see to Questions like "Why are singletons bad practice?" are *opinions*. If it is not a fact, it is an opinion, by definition. There are few facts in practice (and fewer who know them properly), and therefore most of what we do is a result of opinion. That is why we call it "Practice".

Comment: @DanDascalescu Fair point, but the OP not knowing what problems might be caused by X does not resolve subjective or too broad for a question asking "why is X bad". They wanted to know "*specifically if there is a reason why spaces are avoided in slugs*" they must have some scope. Will it break their framework, their class, their browser, all of those - etc. My point was their example was asking something which would likely be too broad/subjective/opinionated etc. My comment was just a simple and basic note or warning.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think that this general form of question can almost always be reformulated into,

> What are the disadvantages or risks of x?

This wording invites clear, objective answers about what potential problems and pitfalls are involved that would cause a programmer to avoid it. If something is widely considered to be bad, then the common disadvantages/risks should be obvious to someone who has an informed opinion. It also discourages discussion about what way is "better," and instead invites pure information so you can make your own informed choice. I believe a question of that form would be on topic, as long as it meets the other normal criteria.

I will note that this does seem pretty broad in terms of what site these questions could belong on. If you're asking about what problems some specific piece of code is likely to run into (you could fairly easily generate a short snippet for the purpose of example) or you have specific questions about a particular standard or language feature, StackOverflow is probably the best fit. If, however, it's about a more general practice, Programmers would probably be a better place. But I think most questions of the form I suggest can find a place somewhere on the StackExchange network.

Comment: Code review is the wrong place. It's either UX.se, programmers.se, or webmasters.se.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but in practice such a question can be closed as "asking for a list."

Comment: @Pacerier I was envisioning a working implementation of a particular pattern/technology/etc., where the asker is concerned that they might have some security holes or lurking bugs. That sounds like a perfect fit for Code Review. I'll rephrase.

Comment: @acbabis That's not a close reason at present. As long as the scope is narrow (one particular practice, one particular library, etc.) enough to be answerable, I don't see the problem.

Comment: I always thought that list type questions that generate a degree of opinionated answers are out of scope?

Comment: List-type questions are simply qualified as "too broad".

Answer (score 16):

Exhibit A:

> Why are spaces not allowed in URLs

Exhibit B:

> Why do some people not like Allman Brace Style?

Can you see the difference?  One of them is a constructive, clearly-answerable question, while the other is not, it being merely opinion.

In a perfect world, we would only rely on the question itself to determine constructiveness.  In reality, sometimes we have to look at the potential answers to a question to determine if the question itself is constructive.

Comment: ... and by "sometimes", you mean "for three of the predefined close reasons and two of the custom close reasons" ;)

Comment: I'm not especially fond of Exhibit A. Perhaps in this specific case, it could be answered, but the general form often comes down to, "Whoever wrote the code/spec decided that and we don't have an answer why." Or is that your point?

Comment: @jpmc26: The answer to Exhibit A can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space

Comment: I'm not really interested in that specific answer... I was taking you at your word that it is answerable. However, many questions of that nature simply don't have an answer beyond picking the brain of whoever made a decision. Is your point that Exhibit A is of that form, but despite that, it can be answered and so is fine, whereas many others would not be fine because they don't have an answer?

Comment: @jpmc26: Read the last paragraph.

Comment: I did. I'm sorry. I'm dense, and I try not to assume when something isn't dead simple and staring me right in the face. Hence why I asked. I'll take that as a yes, even though I'm still not 100% sure.

Comment: Are you suggesting Exhibit B is not answerable? I feel even if it is your preferred bracket placement style, one could come up with a set of disadvantages / reasons as to why people don't like it. The belief that they outweigh the advantages, without evidence or a clear statement of what makes one better over another, would be the opinion, not the disadvantages themselves.

Comment: @MichalCharemza: See [Parkinson's Law of Triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality).

Comment: If you're suggesting I'm focusing on the wrong thing, I have to admit that you may be right...

Comment: Well I dont like Allman brace style either.

Answer (score 7):

I think you'd have some trouble, since Stack Overflow generally prefers specific questions. A vague "why is x usually avoided" would probably require some evidence (statistics) that x is *actually* usually avoided. In the process of finding that evidence, there's a good chance that you'd end up answering your own question.

Ask a question specific to your situation... don't over-generalize it to the point that it becomes unanswerable.

Comment: If I did enough research to find the Answer, I would not pose the Question, and someone else with less time or resources or diligence would not have both. I think SE has made a fetish of question-wording and polish and effort. If you don't like a question, just ignore it! Let normal people be normal, which is to say, imperfect. If you only want "professionals" here, then you must make them prove themselves when they register, and have no ability to ask or answer until they do. Which do you want?

Comment: @nocomprende [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: The community recognizes that there are many different skill levels, but the point of the site is to create a repository of questions for future visitors. A question need not be perfectly polished, but the worse shape it's in, the less useful it will be to anybody except the OP, defeating the purpose of this site.

Comment: Also, the issue you've raised has been addressed [ad nauseam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor).

Comment: I survived as a programmer before the world wide web. Once, due to an error in a printed book (my only resource for the DOS TSR system that I was building to share modems over a Novell network in 1992) I had to go buy another book to realize the problem and correct it. I can do research and solve hard problems. **What made me stop programming was the lack of interaction with other people.**

Comment: @nocomprende - SO is a particular site created for a particular purpose. See [Joel's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ&feature=youtu.be&t=2m31s) about it. It's fine if you think that SO is not a complete solution... [it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180692/why-do-i-receive-downvotes-when-i-am-genuinely-trying-to-learn/180715#180715). But that doesn't mean that SO should change. It means that SO is a tool for some problems and not for others.

Comment: @nocomprende: If you did enough research to find the Answer, then if you feel the Question is important enough you _could_ pose it and self-answer it. Then everyone else with less time or resources or diligence _would_ have both. And you'd personally get the benefit of having your Question & Answer documented online for your own future reference. And who knows, you might score a few more points. :)

Answer (score 1):

I depends on what `x` is in context of the question.  Sometimes there is factual evidence onto why `x` should be avoided.  But other times, it might be opinion-based.

So, it really depends on what `x`, the topic at hand, might be.

Comment: I would go further:  It depends on the answers.  I think in general questions such as these must be left for a while to see if they attract any good ones.

Comment: I agree, if there is no real answer, then it shouldn't be asked.

Answer (score -3):

It seems reasonable to me. Asking "Why is X avoided" is basically shorthand for "Why do most programmers think that X is bad", which is not subjective. There are generally a couple of clear reasons for most common practices like that.

If the question was "Is X bad", then it becomes subjective, and there could be a wide range of views on the subject.

Comment: I think the hard part would be establishing that "most" programmers avoid a certain practice.

Comment: Technically speaking, you don't need to. It's no less reasonable to ask why *some* programmers avoid a certain practice.

Comment: "Most" could become a distraction and source of argument. There's no reason to include that word. Asking a specific question about your circumstance would generally avoid such needless banter. Of course, we are speaking about generalities. There's no hard and fast rule. YMMV.

Comment: Everything is subjective. Or, as Robert M. Pirsig said in *Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance*, "**Everything** is an analogy." Programming did not arrive carved in a stone tablet: we invented it.